# Git: how can i merge two branches by resolving merge conflicts on the tip nodes only?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, rebase

Here is my tree with two branches: dog and cat.

```
A - B - C - D <- dog
|
E - F - G - H - I - J - K - L <- cat
```

Each letter is a commit. I am working on branch cat, and need to get all the updated changes from branch dog.

The commands I am doing are:

```
git checkout cat
git rebase dog
```

I am now getting merge conflicts to resolve, but it seems like it is asking me to resolve merge conflicts from merging A & L, B & L, C & L, and D & L. I only want to resolve the conflicts for merging D & L, as everything in A, B, and C are already reflected in D. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you rebase if you want to merge?

Answer (score 1):

A rebase will basically undo all of your changes (E-L), update your code to D, then make all of your changes (E-L) on top of D.  That's not really what you're looking for.

I think you should do a git merge.

```
git checkout cat
git merge dog
```

From the git-merge man page:

Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their histories diverged from the current
       branch) into the current branch. This command is used by git pull to incorporate changes from another
       repository and can be used by hand to merge changes from one branch into another.

```
   Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "master":

                 A---B---C topic
                /
           D---E---F---G master

   Then "git merge topic" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master
   (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master, and record the result in a new commit along
   with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes.

                 A---B---C topic
                /         \
           D---E---F---G---H master
```